# TextInputLayout/TextInputEditText is causing exception after hint color replacement

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-color, android-attributes

I'm using TextInputEditText inside TextInputLayout and it worked perfectly since today. I just changed attribute for color and it caused this error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #97: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95)
        at com.project.utils.CustomResources$Companion.inflateLayout(CustomResources.kt:62)
        at com.project.screens.Registration.getScreen(RegistrationScreen.kt:34)
        at com.project.registration.CustomViewPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(CustomViewPagerAdapter.kt:40)
        at com.project.registration.CustomViewPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(CustomViewPagerAdapter.kt:25)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1224)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6764)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6764)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6764)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6764)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6764)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23180)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2734)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1583)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1867)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1471)
2021-01-12 12:26:03.681 21736-21736/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7215)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1012)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:823)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:758)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:998)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6735)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030375 a=5}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:546)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getColorStateList(TintTypedArray.java:184)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:561)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:420)
            ... 64 more
```

I'm using custom attributes for my App style, so I added new attribute and just created same selector for that attribute but with different color.

**attrs.xml**

```
<attr name="textInputFieldHint" format="reference"/>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppThemeBlueColor" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
    ...
    <item name="textInputFieldHint">@color/textinputfield_hint_blue</item>
</style>
```

**textinputfield_hint_blue.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/darkBlue" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/darkGrey"/>
</selector>
```

TextInputEditTextStyles:

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/form_edit_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">?attr/textInputFieldHint</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">?attr/textInputFieldHint</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">?attr/textInputFieldOutline</item>
    <item name="errorTextColor">@color/colorRed</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_normal</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/textInputLayout_margin_bottom</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputEditTextStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/form_edit_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">?attr/textInputFieldHint</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">?attr/textColorTertiary</item>
    <item name="errorTextColor">@color/colorRed</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_normal</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/textInputEditText_padding_start</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
</style>
```

I just replaced `textInputFieldOutline` attribute with `textInputFieldHint` attribute. Both are same selectors but different color. And color does exist because its used in other layout components. Seems like some Android bug because it does not have any reason to not work when its the exact same code but different color.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? The hint color is making my app crash too.

Answer (score 0):

In your styles.xml file you have a mistake :

```
<item name="textInputFieldHint">@color/textinputfield_hint_blue</item>
```

You should write a color name from colors.xml file instead of " textinputfield_hint_blue ", which is a xml file itself in drawable folder i guess

Comment: That is selector not color. And it is working like this in general. I have to change hint color based on state and it is done by selector.